# Is there a way of mirroring an inheritance relationship using spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I am new to **Elasticsearch** and **spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch**.

What I'm trying to accomplish is persisting an **inheritance** relationship from **Java** using **Spring Boot** into **Elasticsearch** and then retrieve all the data from the **Elasticsearch** and expose it trough a **REST API** as a **Set**.

For now I have 2 document classes in an **inheritance** relationship annotated with **@Document** and with the same **indexName** property.

When I try to retrieve data via the **ElasticsearchRepository** of the **parent** class it won't map the **child** data from **Elasticsearch** to the **child** class from **Java**.

I found this article on [medium.com](https://medium.com/@mladen.maravic/spring-data-mongodb-my-take-on-inheritance-support-102361c08e3d) for **MonogDB**, it doesn't look that straight forward and I am not sure if it is possible for **Elasticsearch**.

Is there a way of doing that, or is it a bad practice of having multiple **@Documents** with the same **indexName**?

Comment: You can inject `ElasticsearchTemplate` (or `ElasticsearchRestTemplate`) and do the mapping yourself. Using `ElasticsearchTemplate`'s query methods (most are called `getXYZ` or `searchXYZ`) you provide `1.` the query, `2.` the `Class` to map result to, and `3.` the index which should be used by the query.

Comment: *"or it is a bad practice of having multiple @Documents with the same indexName?"* If that's what your use case requires, then it's not bad practice. In general I'd say: If you have no need to search and sort `Parent` and `Child` documents in a single query, then use two indexes. But if you need to query and sort both types together, then storing them in a single index is the way to go.

Comment: @BenjaminM I need to retrieve all the data in a ```Set<Parent>``` and when it is exposed as a response via the ***REST API*** to be able to see the ```Child``` particular members.

Comment: How do you distinguish between those classes in Elasticsearch? You need some kind of discriminator in the database, that tells your application "this document is of type Parent, and this document is of type Child"

Comment: The discriminator is that the ```Child``` class has multiple members, multiple fields

Comment: I don't understand. Can you provide a code snippet of `Parent` and `Child` where we can see the difference?

Comment: ```Class A { Integer foo; }```
```Class B extends A { String bar; }```
B will have everything that A has and bar. Bar is the discriminator.