# Spring data elasticsearch: Using @Document annotation on POJO interface class not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am migrating an application to the latest `spring-boot` version (using maven spring-boot-dependencies with version 2.5.4).

I have an interface called Customer and I have two implementations of that interface (`BusinessCustomer`, `PrivateCustomer`)

The three classes are annotated like that:

```
@Document(indexName = "customers", type = "customer")
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
        property = "customerType"
)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = BusinessCustomer.class, name = "BUSINESS_CUSTOMER"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = PrivateCustomer.class, name = "PRIVATE_CUSTOMER")
})
public interface Customer {
```

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
        property = "customerType",
        defaultImpl = BusinessCustomer.class
)
@Entity
@Document(indexName = "customers", type = "customer")
public class BusinessCustomer implements Serializable, Customer, Cloneable {
```

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
        property = "customerType",
        defaultImpl = PrivateCustomer.class
)
@Entity
@Document(indexName = "customers", type = "customer")
public class PrivateCustomer implements Serializable, Customer, Cloneable {
```

For querying the index "customers" I used to have code like:

```
elasticsearchOperations.count(query, Customer.class);
```

But this is not working anymore. I get an error at runtime:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate Customer using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments ] with root cause org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [Customer]: Specified class is an interface
```

Is it not possible anymore to have two different classes in the same index like this? Has this to be done now with ElasticsearchCustomConversions somehow?

Comment: From the error it seems that the constructor is not visible anymore. Can you show how the POJO is defined? Do you use lombok?

Comment: @AbishekStephen There is no constructor in the Customer class since it is an interface. Lombok is not used. The complete exception is:


Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate Customer using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments ] with root cause 
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [Customer]: Specified class is an interface

Comment: > Failed to instantiate [Customer]: Specified class is an interface
This means your JsonTypeInfo is not mapped to its subtypes JsonSubTypes correctly. Is there any way to denote the interface Customer.class in the JsonTypeInfo declaration?

Comment: @AbishekStephen Nothing changed in the jackson annotations which worked up to now. I think the problem is this:

"Earlier versions of Spring Data Elasticsearch used a Jackson based conversion, Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.2.x introduced the Meta Model Object Mapping."

I don't know how to specify sub type relations with the new meta model instead of the jackson annotations.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68861361/is-there-a-way-of-mirroring-an-inheritance-relationship-using-spring-boot-starte is somehow related to my problem as well.

Comment: So you are storing different objects in one index? How is the mapping for these objects defined?

Comment: And yes, the `MappingElasticsearchConverter` that is used since version 4.0 is working on classes, not interfaces.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch The mapping was defined with jackson annotations. Please see updated code snippets in my initial question. I guess this is not working anymore and I have to switch to two indices like you suggested in your answer. Thanks for suggesting an alternative. I have to figure out if this is applicable for the given scenario.

Comment: I did not mappping an entity to JSON and back, but what is defined for the index mapping (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.14/mapping.html)?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch There is no other mapping. Just the jackson annotations and the Document annotations are used. It worked before. But now since jackson mapping is not supported anymore by spring data elasticsearch it stopped working and I get this MappingInstantiationException. Besides Document and Field annotations how can I define mappings for spring data elasticsearch?

Comment: The index mapping (that's what basically the schema of the documents) is created by Spring Data Elasticsearch from the `@Field` annotaitons on the entity properties, when an index is created by a repository, or when using the `IndexOperations` methods to create an index. And these `@Field` annotations are used as well by the MappingElasticsearchConverter when converting between entities and JSON (respecting field names, date or range conversions etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MappingElasticsearchConverter` in Spring Data Elasticsearch does not work on interfaces but relies on the `@Document` and `@Field` annotations that are set on an entity class.

All Spring Data modules - not only Spring Data Elasticsearch - use the concept of a `PersistentEntity` which is the metainformation about the class to store. And `PersistentProperty`s, this is the metainformation about the properties of the class. For Spring Data Elasticsearch this is information about the field name in Elasticsearch, it's type,
information like date formats etc.

A `@Document` annotated class is associated with an index. Since version 7 Elasticsearch does not support having multiple types in one index anymore.

So you should store your different entities in two indices:

```java
@Document(indexName="business-customers")
class BusinessCustomer {
    // ...
}

@Document(indexName="private-customers")
class PrivateCustomer {
    // ...
}
```

Searching from these two indexes in one call and have the different data returned is possible, I wrote a blog post about how this can be done (https://www.sothawo.com/2021/05/reading-different-entities-from-multiple-indices-with-one-call-using-spring-data-elasticsearch/).